# Expression does not produce a value

Tags: vb.net

"I have a code, but an error comes up (stated in the title)

```
Module Module1
Dim direction As String = ""
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("As you step into the dugeon you realise you are stuck. At the end of the path it converges into 3 paths.")
    While direction <> "Left" And direction <> "right" And direction <> "Middle"
        *direction = Console.WriteLine("Do you want to go left, right, or straight up?")*

    End While
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

End Module
```

Do you know I could fix it? Th code with the stars between it is the bit that doesnt work so I just need th correct code as an answer then i can do it cheers.

Comment: Can you edit my code and then reply?

Comment: Editing the posted code will result in a no-longer-accurate question. I've left an answer with an explanation and some hints. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

`direction = Console.WriteLine(..)` doesn't make sense: Write != Read.

The error is because [`WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf2k8ftb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a *void* result type which "is not, ever, a value". The [void type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.void%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), representing the absence of any value, *cannot* be used in an expressions (including assignments).

The code should probably use `WriteLine` to *display* the text and then use [`ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which returns a *string*, to read some input. Also consider normalizing the input (e.g. use `ToLower/Trim` on the read string) and match the case used in the conditional checks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Module Module1
    Dim direction As String = ""

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("As you step into the dugeon you realise you are stuck. At the end of the path it converges into 3 paths.")
        Do
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to go left, right, or straight up?")
            direction = Console.ReadLine()
        Loop While direction <> "Left" And direction <> "right" And direction <> "Middle"
    End Sub
End Module
```